# Converting lines of text from a file to String Array

Tags: java, drjava

I read the information in a .txt file and now I would like to store the lines of information from the text into a String Array or a variable.

The information in the .txt file is as given:

```
Onesimus, Andrea
BAYV
Twendi, Meghan
RHHS
Threesten, Heidi
MDHS
```

I want to store BAYV, RHHS, MDHS into a different array from the names.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

class testing2 {
 public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {


File Bayviewcamp = new File ("H:\\Profile\\Desktop\\ICS3U\\Bayviewland Camp\\Studentinfo.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (Bayviewcamp);

while (scanner.hasNextLine())
  System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your requirements are not very clear, do you want to store only the uppercase words?

Comment: Please do not use the word *urgent*.

Comment: @GabrielPrá No, I want to store the names (e.g Onesimus, Andrea) into an array and the upper case letters into another array

Comment: They are always in that format : Names and next line is value?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Below code has few restrictions like:

1. There must be format that you said (name and next line value)
2. Array size is 100 by default but you can change as you want
3. By name I mean one line: (Onesimus, Andrea) it's under first index in names array.

   ```
   private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 100;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

     boolean isValue = false;
     File txt = new File("file.txt");
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);

     String[] names = new String[ARRAY_LENGTH];
     String[] values = new String[ARRAY_LENGTH];
     int lineNumber = 0;
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       if (isValue) {
           values[lineNumber / 2] = scanner.nextLine();
       } else {
           names[lineNumber / 2] = scanner.nextLine();
       }
       isValue = !isValue;
       lineNumber++;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
       System.out.println(names[i]);
       System.out.println(values[i]);
     }
   }
   ```

Below code return separated names:

```
private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    boolean isValue = false;
    File txt = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);

    String[] names = new String[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    String[] values = new String[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int namesNumber = 0;
    int valuesNumber = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (!isValue) {
            String tempArrayNames[] = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
            values[valuesNumber++] = tempArrayNames[0].trim();
            values[valuesNumber++] = tempArrayNames[1].trim();
        } else {
            names[namesNumber++] = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        isValue = !isValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether names matches with the regex "`[A-Z]+`"

```
        List<String> upperCaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> lowerCaseList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
              String[] names = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
              for(String name:names) {
                  if(name.matches("[A-Z]+")) {
                      upperCaseList.add(name);
                  }
                  else {
                      lowerCaseList.add(name);
                  }
              }
        }
```

As per your example, some of the names has leading spaces. you may have to trim those spaces before you compare with the regex

```
              for(String name:names) {
                  if(name.trim().matches("[A-Z]+")) {
                      upperCaseList.add(name.trim());
                  }
                  else {
                      lowerCaseList.add(name.trim());
                  }
              }
```